# Use transactional sessions activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html

In the above link author suggest to try transactional sessions, but unfortunately after lots of search on internet not able to get what transactional sessions mean.
And what are its pre-requisite??

The links that i read are:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-transactions-work.html

http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html

Unfortunately still not able to get the meaning and particularly implementation of transactional session and why to use it.

Can any one provide sample reference implementation or tutorial for same. ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately still not able to get the meaning and particularly implementation of transactional session and why to use it.

Its simple if you want to perform an operation on a message , you received a message and did operation if the output is not correct , you dont want to proceed.

let me check for implementation will send if I find on my previous project

Comment: you can take session like this
Session session=connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
and can call commit or rollback accordingly
you can also define configuration for rollback strategy as if rollback happen what needs to be done eg. you can send message to dead letter queue etc

Comment: it would be more clear if I can have some reference implementation that I could run , and use debugger to trace what is hapenning. I would be glad if you can point to some tutorial